# Doctrine 2 One-To-Many retrieving many side returns an empty collection

Tags: php, doctrine, one-to-many

I am working on a project that utilizes Zend Framework 1.12 integrated with doctrine 2. I am having trouble with a Bidirectional One-to-Many relation in said project.
The two entities concerning my problem are Team and Player; a team can have many players.

The Team Entity:

```
namespace Entities;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection,
    Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Repositories\TeamRepository")
 * @Table(name="team")
 */
class Team extends Entity{

/**
 * @Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Player", mappedBy="team")
 */
protected $players;

public function __construct() {
    $this->players = new ArrayCollection();
}


public function getName(){
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
    return $this;
}

public function getPlayers() {
    return $this->players;
}
```

And the Player Entity:

```
namespace Entities;

/**
* @Entity(repositoryClass="Repositories\PlayerRepository")
* @Table(name="player")
*/
class Player extends Entity{

    public function __construct() {

    }

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Team", inversedBy="players")
     * @JoinColumn(name="team_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $team;

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getTeam() {
        return $this->team;
    }

    public function setTeam($team) {
        $this->team = $team;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Now in my player controller for example I can retrieve a player and get the team name

```
$oPlayer    = $this->_em->find('Entities\Player', $player_id);
$teamname   = $oPlayer->getTeam()->getName();
```

This works as expected and I successfully obtain the name of the players team.
However the other way around does not work. I can not retrieve all the players given a team

```
$oTeam = $this->_em->find('Entities\Team', $team_id);
$oPlayers = $oTeam->getPlayers();
```

When I var_dump this the result looks like

```
object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)#238 (9) {
  ["snapshot":"Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["owner":"Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection":private]=>
  object(Entities\Team)#195 (7) {
     ...
  }
```

Note that a persistenCollection seems to be build, however the array is empty.
I have read the doctrine manual extensively and googled my behind off and am now at a loss.

Also the fact that there is no error message, I am having a hard time solving this problem.
Any pointers would be more than welcome.

Comment: Very strange, most because the `$team` field of `Player` entity seems populated, and your implementation is [canonical](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/association-mapping.html). Try to provide the `setPlayers()` method, just to make a `var_dump` of collection being passed, if any.

Comment: Use `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump();` instead of `var_dump()`

Comment: Just for my reference, what is the definition of canonical? Could not find it in the link. I tried defining the setter does not seem to make a difference. @Keyne I tried the debug dump and the result is 'string(4) "team"' , this looks like it might be a usefull hint?

Comment: It should output the object... not a string. Perhaps you're mixing some names.

Comment: $oTeam = $this->_em->find('Entities\Team', $team_id);
\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($oTeam);  this returns string(4) "team"  however the var_dump of the same $oTeam returns the object.

Comment: Hard to tell you what's going on... if you loop through the `$oPlayers` it doesn't work? `foreach($oPlayers as $player) echo $player->getName();`

Comment: It is getting weirder and weirder. Even foreach($oPlayers as $player) echo $player->getName(); returns a white page (read the layout is not rendered) and string(4) "team" is returned. I checked the error_logs but no error is reported nor any notices. The weirdest thing though is; I replaced the echo with "echo 'test'" and it still returns string(4) "team"!! No php after the foreach is getting executed. So looping over the 'empty' $oPlayers collection is causing problems. question remains why it is empty. Thanks for your help so far by the way

Comment: Time to use a interactive debugger (e.g. xDebugger) with `break-points` within your IDE.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem has been resolved. I have been trying to puzzle the solution together for posterity but have come to the conclusion that I no longer have the files where I now suspect the original error was located. I managed to get a working copy derived from another project. By brute force 'diff'-ing and replacing code I traced the error of the empty array of the persistent collection, to my bootstrap and resources/doctrine.php config file, which unfortunately I do not have any longer and therefore can not confirm this. With string(4) "team" still being returned (as discussed in the comments) embarrassingly I finally found out that it was just due to a die() I put in the doctrine library file and forgot about.